# Issue accessing Hive JDBC via Knox and configuring Hive in Ranger

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, truststore

We have HDP-2.2 cluster with FreeIPA configured.But when we are trying to access hive jdbc via knox we are facing issue.Following is the JDBC URI that we are using:

> jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxxxxxx:8443/;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/var/lib/knox/data/security/keystores/gateway.jks;trustStorePassword=xxxxxxxxxxxx?hive.server2.transport.mode=http;hive.server2.thrift.http.path=gateway/default/hive

Below is the error we are getting:
_

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
>   (state=08S01,code=0)

It seems that password of trustStore does not match as that of mentioned in JDBC URI.We tried changing the Knox Master password but ambari does not allow to change the it.Is their any way wherein we can change the trustStore password and create new knox master? Will it affect the other services if the master secret password is changed?

In addition to that if we use the same URI for creating hive repository in Ranger we get _"Connection failed" _error.Is the same JDBC URI to be used in ranger to create repository for hive?

**Note: If we set hive transport mode to "binary" instead of "HTTP" then we are able to create repository in ranger but in that case hive over knox will not work as it requires "HTTP" mode**

Comment: Sachin, Did you get a solution for this ? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Yes I got the solution actually i reset the keystore password and that solved my issue

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I did reset on the keystore password but it didn't help!

Comment: Oh then i need to know whether you have performed proper steps:
1) Have you imported the knox certificate to ranger admin conf directory
2) Have you restarted the ranger service by exporting JAVA_OPTS with path to certificate something like this :export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${certs_with_knox}"

Comment: Hi Sachin, I am trying to first configure on the HDP sandbox, I tried running/accessing webHDFS and MapReduce using Knox worked fine. But beeline connection seems to be an issue. BTW: I have not made any changes to the sandbox do I still need to import knox certificate? For now I've not configured the Ranger for Sandbox.  What do you think I might be missing?

Comment: If you are using sandbox then i think you dont need to import the certificate.Coming to the issue of hive is your hive running in binary mode or http mode if http mode and if you have configured knox then instead of using hive port you have to use knox port refer to this link:http://hortonworks.com/blog/secure-jdbc-odbc-clients-access-hiveserver2/

Comment: Sachin - why don't you post your solution as an answer to your own question? It should help future users that way, better than comments will.

Comment: @SachinJanani..Sachin i was able to connect JDBC client using knox with my user and password(user exists on openLDAP ) but i am not able to understand why the default beeline connection is still working ..!connect jdbc:hive2://sandbox:10001/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=cliservice..is it happening at your end also

Comment: @anwaar_hell Default beeline will also work.But in order to have security you have to close all port for outsiders except knox.This will ensure that all traffic will go through the knox.Hope it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

1. Check gateway.jks location, permissions and keystore password.
2. Stop Knox, remove *.jceks from ${KNOX_HOME}/security/keystores and stark Knox again.